# Use generate series to fill in missing values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like so -

```
First   Last    Client          iso_week  count
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_01   1
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_02   1
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_04   2
Angela  Myers   New Western     2018_03   3
```

How do I use generate_series to get this output -

```
First   Last    Client          iso_week  count
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_01   1
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_02   1
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_03   0
Aaron   Cook    AVALON          2018_04   2
Angela  Myers   New Western     2018_01   0
Angela  Myers   New Western     2018_02   0
Angela  Myers   New Western     2018_03   3
Angela  Myers   New Western     2018_04   0
```

I need to add zeros in the middle where months are missing for all people in the table. For example, `Aaron Cook` had `March 2018` data missing and that is why a record was created for `2018_03` and zero was added to the count of that record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `generate_series` to stack the data with `0` counts and `sum` them up later in the final select

```
with cte as

(select frst, lst, client, iso_week, cnt
 from t
 union
 select frst, lst, client, left(iso_week,5)||trim(to_char(generate_series(1,12),'00')), 0
 from t)
                                                  
 select frst, lst, client, iso_week, sum(cnt) as cnt
 from cte
 group by frst, lst, client, iso_week;
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kK4S84Cz3SjHjZg49oUKEN/2)

I later realized I could have implemented it more easily

```
 select frst, lst, client, iso_week, cnt
 from t
 union all
 select frst, lst, client, left(iso_week,5)||trim(to_char(generate_series(1,12),'00')), 0
 from t
 except
 select frst, lst, client, iso_week, 0
 from t;
```

Both of these approaches offer simplicity at the expense of performance. If performance becomes an issue, I suggest dumping `distinct frst, lst, client, left(iso_week,5)` into another temp table before concatenating the output of `generate_series`. As is, you're multiplying the size of your data by at least 12. Having said that, if you're working with an already aggregated data that just just a couple hundred or thousands rows, performance shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select c.client, c.first, c.last, yw.iso_week,
       coalesce(t.count, 0)
from (select '2018_' || to_char(ts.wek, '00') as iso_week
      from generate_series(1, 5) gs(wk)
     ) yw cross join
     (select distinct client, first, last from t) c left join
     t
     on t.iso_week = yw.iso_week and t.client = c.client
```

Comment: This solution is hard coded to 2018. What if I had data for 2019, 2020, 2021 and forward as well? Is there a way to generalize it?

Comment: @Aaron . . . That is the question that you asked.  No, it is not hard at all to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the results of a recursive CTE onto your original data:

```
with recursive d_ranges(w) as (
    select to_date('2018 01', 'YYYY MM')::text
    union all
    select (to_date(w, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 month')::text from d_ranges where to_date(w, 'YYYY-MM-DD') < to_date('2018 04', 'YYYY MM')
),
d_users as (
   select distinct u.fst, u.lst, u.client from users u
)
select s.*, case when u.cnt is null then 0 else u.cnt end 
from (select u.*, to_char(to_date(r.w, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY_MM') w 
      from d_users u cross join d_ranges r) s 
left join users u on u.iso_week = s.w and u.fst = s.fst and u.lst = s.lst and u.client = s.client
order by s.fst, s.lst, s.client, s.w;
```